# window10 the system cannot find the path specified, but path has been added

Tags: python, windows, cmd, path

I am trying to use windows10's cmd to run a python code. But it shows the system cannot find the path. I have already checked the path in the system, and also using echo %path% from the cmd, the correct directory is shown in the system. But I am still getting this error.

Could anyone please help me out?

Thank you very much
[please see the picture here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3A5C2.png)

Comment: Include the actual code, error text, and no screenshots. But the error sounds pretty self-explanatory.

Comment: is C:\python the place where you installed your actual python distribution? or is it the directory where you keep your scripts? does this work? python.exe --version

Comment: @mrxra C:\python is the place I installed Python, where python.exe is inside it.

Comment: python.exe doesn't search `PATH` for the script to run. If it's a relative path, it gets resolved against the current working directory or per-drive working directory (e.g. "Z:script.py" is a drive-relative path that depends on the working directory on drive Z:). That said, the error message in your picture is strange. The message should be something like "python: can't open file 'execute_command.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory".

Comment: Thank you guys, the problem has been solve, the reason seems that I didn't set the path correctly.

Comment: Do you mean the working directory? The `PATH` value seems fine in the picture: `...;C:\python\Scripts\;C:\python\;...`, if that's where it's installed.

Answer (score 0):

It may have been added to the path incorrectly. See this page on how to add it to the path: https://superuser.com/questions/143119/how-do-i-add-python-to-the-windows-path

After trying this, restart your computer.

Comment: @user1933836 Are you sure that the python exe is in that folder? My python executable is under "\Python\Python38-32\python.exe".

Comment: yes, I am sure about that. I followed what you said, and after I create a new .py file, it then works. maybe the problem is I reinstall python too many times and changed the directory many times

Answer (score 0):

your working directory needs to be the directory in which your program is saved. is your program saved in the python directory? if not then go to the working directory using cd command and then run the python command.

Answer (score 0):

Go to Settings / Apps & features / App execution aliases and make sure the aliases for python's App installer are disabled (Off).